# Example of bijective continuous map for which the induced map between the fundamental group is not an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Is there any bijective continuous map for which the induced map between the fundamental group is not an isomorphism?

My attempt: If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is any bijective continuous map, then it is an homeomorphism if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. And we know that homemorphic spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups. I cannot think of any specific examples.

Answer (score 9):

A simple counterexample is everyone's favorite bijective continuous non-homeomorphism:
$$f : [0,1) \to S^1, \quad f(t) = (\cos(2 \pi t), \sin(2 \pi t))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another counterexample is the identity mapping $I : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ where the topology on the domain is the discrete topology and the topology on the codomain is the usual topology. You can construct a gazillion counterexamples along these lines.

Comment: Isn't the induced map on $\pi_1$ an isomorphism in this case (for any chosen base points)?  But I agree this works if you change both $\mathbb{R}s$ to, e.g. $S^1$s.